# Can MediaElement be set to auto play a video file?

Tags: mediaelement.js

Can MediaElement.js - HTML5 Video & Audio Player be set to automatically play the video on load?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add `autoplay` as attribute to the video tag.

Comment: Example: <audio src="http://stream.zeno.fm/dkxftg6k7tzuv" width="320" height="50" autoplay  />